# For sets S and T, why does Python's S -= T take O(len(T)) and not O(len(S))?

Tags: python, big-o, python-internals

The Set entries in [this Python time complexity table](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) say, and the comments below confirm, that `S.difference_update(T)` takes time O(len(T)) while `S - T` takes O(len(S)). The reason given is that the algorithm for the first is "for every element in T remove it from S", while the algorithm for the second is "for every element in S add it to the new set, if not in T".

Wouldn't the algorithm "for every element in S, remove it from S if it's in T" work identically well and be O(len(S))? Why not just do whichever is shorter?

I think I'm not seeing something.

Comment: You'd still have to add the elements to the new set before you could remove them.

Comment: My question is about the `S.difference_update(T)` case, where we're not creating a new set because we're just modifying things in-place, I believe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, there is not really a requirement in the operation that S is larger than T. It’s easily possible that `T` is actually much larger than S:

```
>>> S = {1, 2, 3}
>>> T = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
>>> S - T
{1, 2}
```

So, choosing one or the other algorithm for all operation would be an arbitrary choice since you simply don’t know which is actually shorter (if you don’t know the sets).

But in general, it does not really matter. Both S and T are inputs and both `O(|T|)` and `O(|S|)` is still `O(n)`, i.e. linear. So it’s not really an issue anyway.

---

I’ve checked with [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/setobject.c) to verify further what exactly is happening.

- `S.difference(T)`, `S - T` ([`set_difference`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/setobject.c#l1548)): This calculates the difference between two set objects. It iterates over the elements in S and checks for each if it is included in T. If it’s not, it is added to the result set.

  If `S` is much larger than `T`, the implementation actually copies S and performs a `S' -= T`. As this leaves many items in S, it’s cheaper than starting with an empty set and keep adding elements from S.
- `S.difference_update(T)` ([`set_difference_update`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/setobject.c#l1518)): First of all, this accepts *multiple* arguments. So technically, it cannot check for T’s length and swap simply because there are multiple Ts around. And even more important, it supports Ts that are not sets themselves (any iterable), so it can only work by iterating through those iterables and remove those items from the set.

  So for this, iterating over `S` isn’t actually possible (since we don’t have constant member check in the Ts).

So as it turns out, there is some reason why it happens like this. Those reasons are mostly hidden in the actual set method instead of the operator implementations (which do use the methods internally though). While you could possibly micro-optimize a few special cases further, as per above, this won’t give you that much improvements though as technically, you still stay `O(n)`. And in usual applications (especially in Python), it’s unlikely that such an operation will be your bottleneck.

Comment: Can't we find out the size of sets at runtime -- is it correct that set size lookup is O(1)? Re: the order -- the reason this came up for me was because I had a situation where |T| = O(n) but |S| = O(1).

Comment: Ah, thanks for elaborating. So it seems like a big factor is that since difference_update() accepts any iterable, it has no way to tell the length a priori, while difference() only accepts sets, which have sizes.